# firebase function with realtime database error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase function and trying to use firebase function with Realtime database (Emulator suite).But when i try to set the value in firebase using the firebase function,it gives an error and doesn't set the value in database.

Error:

```
17:33:14
I
function[us-central1-textToLength]
[2021-11-05T12:03:14.194Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: wss:// URL used, but browser isn't known to support websockets.  Trying anyway. 
17:34:18
I
function[us-central1-textToLength]
[2021-11-05T12:04:18.762Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: wss:// URL used, but browser isn't known to support websockets.  Trying anyway. 
17:35:06
I
function[us-central1-textToLength]
[2021-11-05T12:05:06.473Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: wss:// URL used, but browser isn't known to support websockets.  Trying anyway. 
17:35:54
I
function[us-central1-textToLength]
[2021-11-05T12:05:54.409Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: wss:// URL used, but browser isn't known to support websockets.  Trying anyway.
```

firebase function code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(); 

var database = admin.database();

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.textToLength = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var tex = request.query.text;
    var textLength = tex.length;
    console.log(textLength);
    database.ref().child('test').set("op");
    response.send(String(textLength));
});
```

dependencies :

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "@firebase/database-compat": "0.1.2" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

npm installed packages

```
+-- @firebase/app-compat@0.1.7
| +-- @firebase/app@0.7.6
| | +-- @firebase/component@0.5.8
| | | +-- @firebase/util@1.4.1 deduped
| | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | +-- @firebase/logger@0.3.1
| | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | +-- @firebase/util@1.4.1
| | | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| +-- @firebase/component@0.5.8
| | +-- @firebase/util@1.4.1 deduped
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| +-- @firebase/logger@0.3.1
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| +-- @firebase/util@1.4.1
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| `-- tslib@2.3.1
+-- @firebase/database-compat@0.1.2
| +-- @firebase/component@0.5.7
| | +-- @firebase/util@1.4.0 deduped
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| +-- @firebase/database@0.12.2
| | +-- @firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.6
| | +-- @firebase/component@0.5.7 deduped
| | +-- @firebase/logger@0.3.0 deduped
| | +-- @firebase/util@1.4.0 deduped
| | +-- faye-websocket@0.11.4
| | | `-- websocket-driver@0.7.4
| | |   +-- http-parser-js@0.5.3
| | |   +-- safe-buffer@5.2.1 deduped
| | |   `-- websocket-extensions@0.1.4
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| +-- @firebase/database-types@0.9.1
| | +-- @firebase/app-types@0.7.0
| | `-- @firebase/util@1.4.0 deduped
| +-- @firebase/logger@0.3.0
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| +-- @firebase/util@1.4.0
| | `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
| `-- tslib@2.3.1 deduped
`-- firebase-admin@10.0.0
  +-- @firebase/database-compat@0.1.2 deduped
  +-- @firebase/database-types@0.7.3
  | `-- @firebase/app-types@0.6.3
  +-- @google-cloud/firestore@4.15.1
  | +-- fast-deep-equal@3.1.3
  | +-- functional-red-black-tree@1.0.1
  | +-- google-gax@2.28.0
```

Comment: got the same issue toady.. was working fine yesterday

Comment: Frank Puffelen, please, help us with your team. I'm having a production issue with these Socket errors and I can't solve that in any way.

Comment: Same issue here while trying to test a google cloud function on a local machine (Mac/M1).

Comment: Exactly same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the meantime, if you are on the latest Admin SDK version, you can pin @firebase/database-compat to version 0.1.2 in your package.json file as a temporary fix.
>
> `"dependencies": { "@firebase/database-compat": "0.1.2" }`
>
> This works for me.

Ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1487

I referred this example and it worked but for this to work **rebuild your package-lock.json file** by removing node_modules folder and package_lock.json file and running `npm install --package-lock-only`

Comment: I tried but this is not working. I removed the node_module folder and package_lock.json. Then I run the command npm install --package-lock-only inside my fucnction folder. I then added "@firebase/database-compat": "0.1.2" in my package.json dependences. When I serve or deploy the website I keep having the same error "FIREBASE WARNING: wss:// URL used, but browser isn't known to support websockets.". With identical code but for firestore all is working fine. Any suggestions to fix this bug?

Comment: From the github issues ,i got to know that this issue was due to the new @firebase/database package released ,downgradding to lower version fixed this issue for almost all developers.So i think you are doing somthing wrong

Comment: yes now it's working. I see they officially fixed the bug

Answer (score 10):

In the meantime, if you are on the latest Admin SDK version, you can pin @firebase/database-compat to version 0.1.2 in your package.json file as a temporary fix.

"dependencies": {
"@firebase/database-compat": "0.1.2"
}

This works for me.

Ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1487

Comment: I am getting the same error/warning again,could you please see my package.json is correct or not

Comment: Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: I tried. Not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely known issue currently they are working on a fix like Kasirajan suggested https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1487#issuecomment-962219551. This fix worked for us. Wanted to upvote his comment but my reputation is still low haha but I can verify that works.

Comment: I tried using that fix ,but it giving me the same warning ,u can check the above attached code of package.json where i have used the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to the cause of that log message, but I do see that you are returning a response from your function before it completes all of its work. In a deployed function, as soon as the function returns, **all further actions should be treated as if they will never be executed** [as documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities). An "inactive" function might be terminated at any time, is severely throttled and any network calls you make (like setting data in the RTDB) may never be executed.

I know you are new to this, but its a good habit to get into now: don't assume the person calling your function is you. Check for problems like missing query parameters and dodgy data before you blindly action something. The Admin SDK bypasses your database's security rules and if you are not careful a malicious user can cause some damage (e.g. a user that updates `/users/$theirUid/roles/admin` to `true`).

```js
exports.textToLength = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const { text: queryText } = request.query;
    
    if (!queryText)
      return response.status(400).send("Missing ?text");
    if (typeof queryText !== 'string')
      return response.status(400).send("Bad value for ?text");

    const textLength = queryText.length;
    
    database.ref()
      .child('test')
      .set("op")
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`Successfully updated /test/op to ${textLength}`);
        response.send(String(textLength))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(`Failed to update /test/op to ${textLength}: `, error);
        response.status(500).send(`Failed to update database to ${textLength}`)
      });
    ;
});
```

**Note:** When deploying [HTTPS Request functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), don't forget to handle [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: I am getting the same error again in Firebase emulator suite.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be caused from a recent release of one of the @firebase/* packages. I don't know exactly which version is bad yet, but I was able to resolve the issue by reverting my most recent change to my yarn.lock file.

Here are my current @firebase dependency versions, and I'm no longer experiencing the issue:

```
"@firebase/analytics-types@0.4.0":
  version "0.4.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/analytics-types/-/analytics-types-0.4.0.tgz#d6716f9fa36a6e340bc0ecfe68af325aa6f60508"
  integrity sha512-Jj2xW+8+8XPfWGkv9HPv/uR+Qrmq37NPYT352wf7MvE9LrstpLVmFg3LqG6MCRr5miLAom5sen2gZ+iOhVDeRA==

"@firebase/analytics@0.6.4":
  version "0.6.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/analytics/-/analytics-0.6.4.tgz#1e0c446e0045c94077f2d06ff3ba33e86d860398"
  integrity sha512-Lhnk5pXeDKoPf1b2cggWQaqCtNq+jn6IkhHMIo+7VztVt3i8ovnGuhAn/0hLC+XxvVWJ9q6CXIoGStkwvecDoA==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/analytics-types" "0.4.0"
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.20"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/analytics@0.6.5":
  version "0.6.5"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/analytics/-/analytics-0.6.5.tgz#9f28575ba13e7f04cf1ae506322f11fb80bcb611"
  integrity sha512-0yNdAtLRIS7wTs8eUSPHfQyypAbGha0MVpfnl18CTq1sLpdzHICn7CyCMYhc0ewlFdTCIHLjw4ZQoSTwtBHfkQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/analytics-types" "0.4.0"
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.21"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/app-types@0.6.1":
  version "0.6.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/app-types/-/app-types-0.6.1.tgz#dcbd23030a71c0c74fc95d4a3f75ba81653850e9"
  integrity sha512-L/ZnJRAq7F++utfuoTKX4CLBG5YR7tFO3PLzG1/oXXKEezJ0kRL3CMRoueBEmTCzVb/6SIs2Qlaw++uDgi5Xyg==

"@firebase/app-types@0.6.3":
  version "0.6.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/app-types/-/app-types-0.6.3.tgz#3f10514786aad846d74cd63cb693556309918f4b"
  integrity sha512-/M13DPPati7FQHEQ9Minjk1HGLm/4K4gs9bR4rzLCWJg64yGtVC0zNg9gDpkw9yc2cvol/mNFxqTtd4geGrwdw==

"@firebase/app-types@0.7.0":
  version "0.7.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/app-types/-/app-types-0.7.0.tgz#c9e16d1b8bed1a991840b8d2a725fb58d0b5899f"
  integrity sha512-6fbHQwDv2jp/v6bXhBw2eSRbNBpxHcd1NBF864UksSMVIqIyri9qpJB1Mn6sGZE+bnDsSQBC5j2TbMxYsJQkQg==

"@firebase/app@0.6.15":
  version "0.6.15"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/app/-/app-0.6.15.tgz#a426f02eb7210d1ecc77d49296bbb1ec8481a791"
  integrity sha512-VfULP09cci4xk+iAU6CB2CUNU/vbpAOoUleDdspXFphV9Yw36anb8RjaHGcN1DRR7LNb7vznNJXHk8FJhC8VWQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/app-types" "0.6.1"
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    dom-storage "2.1.0"
    tslib "^1.11.1"
    xmlhttprequest "1.8.0"

"@firebase/app@0.6.16":
  version "0.6.16"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/app/-/app-0.6.16.tgz#d87f3d70e59dd44e8f14fd45a575b8ffe58be406"
  integrity sha512-QGqfvDQ4AK54y2ysttdgtTsyuLGfN0OksdmWSHLDs7HBJg9nJkZUuFA/cJ1cftpPSVxpCbnro+OU1FtRgapzAA==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/app-types" "0.6.1"
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    dom-storage "2.1.0"
    tslib "^2.0.0"
    xmlhttprequest "1.8.0"

"@firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.5":
  version "0.1.5"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/auth-interop-types/-/auth-interop-types-0.1.5.tgz#9fc9bd7c879f16b8d1bb08373a0f48c3a8b74557"
  integrity sha512-88h74TMQ6wXChPA6h9Q3E1Jg6TkTHep2+k63OWg3s0ozyGVMeY+TTOti7PFPzq5RhszQPQOoCi59es4MaRvgCw==

"@firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.6":
  version "0.1.6"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/auth-interop-types/-/auth-interop-types-0.1.6.tgz#5ce13fc1c527ad36f1bb1322c4492680a6cf4964"
  integrity sha512-etIi92fW3CctsmR9e3sYM3Uqnoq861M0Id9mdOPF6PWIg38BXL5k4upCNBggGUpLIS0H1grMOvy/wn1xymwe2g==

"@firebase/auth-types@0.10.2":
  version "0.10.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/auth-types/-/auth-types-0.10.2.tgz#3fad953380c447b7545122430a4c7a9bc8355001"
  integrity sha512-0GMWVWh5TBCYIQfVerxzDsuvhoFpK0++O9LtP3FWkwYo7EAxp6w0cftAg/8ntU1E5Wg56Ry0b6ti/YGP6g0jlg==

"@firebase/auth@0.16.4":
  version "0.16.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/auth/-/auth-0.16.4.tgz#6249d80f1e974b0db122930ae9fac885eccead5c"
  integrity sha512-zgHPK6/uL6+nAyG9zqammHTF1MQpAN7z/jVRLYkDZS4l81H08b2SzApLbRfW/fmy665xqb5MK7sVH0V1wsiCNw==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/auth-types" "0.10.2"

"@firebase/component@0.2.0":
  version "0.2.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/component/-/component-0.2.0.tgz#9d48327b3377b84ef22266ec6ab13416ea174c0a"
  integrity sha512-QJJxMEzLRMWjujPBrrS32BScg1wmdY/dZWR8nAEzyC8WKQsNevYR9ZKLbBYxaN0umH9yf5C40kwmy+gI8jStPw==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/component@0.2.1":
  version "0.2.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/component/-/component-0.2.1.tgz#998e2909f87993a2ad7ea718dbf109cd8f5c7ca3"
  integrity sha512-WfBFABfKYcRFjgMA7ydPLokSa+GkuZd+FD00KrZLAfslpHxs6cCFXdklvP8NEb1oDLqYakRXBqWdelH9/Whacg==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/component@0.5.7":
  version "0.5.7"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/component/-/component-0.5.7.tgz#a50c5fbd14a2136a99ade6f59f53498729c0f174"
  integrity sha512-CiAHUPXh2hn/lpzMShNmfAxHNQhKQwmQUJSYMPCjf2bCCt4Z2vLGpS+UWEuNFm9Zf8LNmkS+Z+U/s4Obi5carg==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/util" "1.4.0"
    tslib "^2.1.0"

"@firebase/database-compat@^0.1.1":
  version "0.1.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/database-compat/-/database-compat-0.1.1.tgz#9fe69e3bd3f71d29011bb6ca793f38edb65ca536"
  integrity sha512-K3DFWiw0YkLZtlfA9TOGPw6zVXKu5dQ1XqIGztUufFVRYW8IizReXVxzSSmJNR4Adr2LiU9j66Wenc6e5UfwaQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.5.7"
    "@firebase/database" "0.12.1"
    "@firebase/database-types" "0.9.1"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.3.0"
    "@firebase/util" "1.4.0"
    tslib "^2.1.0"

"@firebase/database-types@0.7.0":
  version "0.7.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/database-types/-/database-types-0.7.0.tgz#ab140d178ded676e60d8ade8c8f13de8e01e7e1e"
  integrity sha512-FduQmPpUUOHgbOt7/vWlC1ntSLMEqqYessdQ/ODd7RFWm53iVa0T1mpIDtNwqd8gW3k7cajjSjcLjfQGtvLGDg==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/app-types" "0.6.1"

"@firebase/database-types@0.9.1":
  version "0.9.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/database-types/-/database-types-0.9.1.tgz#0cab989e8154d812b535d80f23c1578b1d391f5f"
  integrity sha512-RUixK/YrbpxbfdE+nYP0wMcEsz1xPTnafP0q3UlSS/+fW744OITKtR1J0cMRaXbvY7EH0wUVTNVkrtgxYY8IgQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/app-types" "0.7.0"
    "@firebase/util" "1.4.0"

"@firebase/database-types@^0.7.2":
  version "0.7.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/database-types/-/database-types-0.7.3.tgz#819f16dd4c767c864b460004458620f265a3f735"
  integrity sha512-dSOJmhKQ0nL8O4EQMRNGpSExWCXeHtH57gGg0BfNAdWcKhC8/4Y+qfKLfWXzyHvrSecpLmO0SmAi/iK2D5fp5A==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/app-types" "0.6.3"

"@firebase/database@0.12.1":
  version "0.12.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/database/-/database-0.12.1.tgz#7e43f27ac4057858d5bd0dd371b134b304fecdb0"
  integrity sha512-Ethk0hc476qnkSKNBa+8Yc7iM8AO69HYWsaD+QUC983FZtnuMyNLHtEeSUbLQYvyHo7cOjcc52slop14WmfZeQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/auth-interop-types" "0.1.6"
    "@firebase/component" "0.5.7"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.3.0"
    "@firebase/util" "1.4.0"
    faye-websocket "0.11.4"
    tslib "^2.1.0"

"@firebase/database@0.9.4":
  version "0.9.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/database/-/database-0.9.4.tgz#7f108ad96f099beae78c06a86f81edf4302fd4c4"
  integrity sha512-Fw2bA4OyxAMqLy8xtoZKlUAuDWjjH/z4AInRTAzHxgegXDbu0UK+VM0pmY44RuM2cmnVY4aW6xLXAdDKTY1aJQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/auth-interop-types" "0.1.5"
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/database-types" "0.7.0"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    faye-websocket "0.11.3"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/database@0.9.5":
  version "0.9.5"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/database/-/database-0.9.5.tgz#3f4f1dac759d138cf7cfaef5121640cba506f700"
  integrity sha512-sfS5ZvU7UqztMAP9y3t/AQRNhqDrHJT6/W1JBmEivjSxf1MLLbCafZMFbksuvl2iog73wOGDuoDzSHvhtSQvvg==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/auth-interop-types" "0.1.5"
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/database-types" "0.7.0"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    faye-websocket "0.11.3"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/firestore-types@2.1.0":
  version "2.1.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/firestore-types/-/firestore-types-2.1.0.tgz#ad406c6fd7f0eae7ea52979f712daa0166aef665"
  integrity sha512-jietErBWihMvJkqqEquQy5GgoEwzHnMXXC/TsVoe9FPysXm1/AeJS12taS7ZYvenAtyvL/AEJyKrRKRh4adcJQ==

"@firebase/firestore-types@2.2.0":
  version "2.2.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/firestore-types/-/firestore-types-2.2.0.tgz#9a3f3f2906232c3b4a726d988a6ef077f35f9093"
  integrity sha512-5kZZtQ32FIRJP1029dw+ZVNRCclKOErHv1+Xn0pw/5Fq3dxroA/ZyFHqDu+uV52AyWHhNLjCqX43ibm4YqOzRw==

"@firebase/firestore@2.1.7":
  version "2.1.7"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/firestore/-/firestore-2.1.7.tgz#039d1d469bd14d89a2d091ec7887a92cc7ab11a7"
  integrity sha512-sh+aX6udS8a+rwmlJO4zJwvoMC1D2x1CiPvj0nFYWhILRKWvztk/bOA3lT2FWcHY4kr/7x+CnqfwtiOSaufdNQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/firestore-types" "2.1.0"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    "@firebase/webchannel-wrapper" "0.4.1"
    "@grpc/grpc-js" "^1.0.0"
    "@grpc/proto-loader" "^0.5.0"
    node-fetch "2.6.1"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/firestore@2.2.0":
  version "2.2.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/firestore/-/firestore-2.2.0.tgz#b7cf2d6a65b432bec43430f1d9f696c07b881e90"
  integrity sha512-/p0oR73zgAlEHgqCIt5v2m8ADOign6APkZ0QG5bJQVSDqPXjB89ktI3v8x0qtRtzKm/pd3lmyoD/raOh/ItsZA==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/firestore-types" "2.2.0"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    "@firebase/webchannel-wrapper" "0.4.1"
    "@grpc/grpc-js" "^1.0.0"
    "@grpc/proto-loader" "^0.5.0"
    node-fetch "2.6.1"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/functions-types@0.4.0":
  version "0.4.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/functions-types/-/functions-types-0.4.0.tgz#0b789f4fe9a9c0b987606c4da10139345b40f6b9"
  integrity sha512-3KElyO3887HNxtxNF1ytGFrNmqD+hheqjwmT3sI09FaDCuaxGbOnsXAXH2eQ049XRXw9YQpHMgYws/aUNgXVyQ==

"@firebase/functions@0.6.2":
  version "0.6.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/functions/-/functions-0.6.2.tgz#5ed6822248c14a4287ec156afc980d76d57e470a"
  integrity sha512-f+NxRd0k5RBPZUPj8lykeNMku8TpJTgZaRd3T6cXb8HbmSg/VY7uxQSGOXe11X2gSv/TvcwTQttViFzRMDs7CQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/functions-types" "0.4.0"
    "@firebase/messaging-types" "0.5.0"
    node-fetch "2.6.1"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/functions@0.6.3":
  version "0.6.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/functions/-/functions-0.6.3.tgz#015e1efd1cf6749dddbdc056215d3035b43d000c"
  integrity sha512-02dqjin4V9PvuZLU6d14azyRZZ5cUSPT5CvE2SbGjAcXYdlFIg5Cy6T50dl48UsbmmNO40kXNB1dGESp2A4cWw==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/functions-types" "0.4.0"
    "@firebase/messaging-types" "0.5.0"
    node-fetch "2.6.1"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/installations-types@0.3.4":
  version "0.3.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/installations-types/-/installations-types-0.3.4.tgz#589a941d713f4f64bf9f4feb7f463505bab1afa2"
  integrity sha512-RfePJFovmdIXb6rYwtngyxuEcWnOrzdZd9m7xAW0gRxDIjBT20n3BOhjpmgRWXo/DAxRmS7bRjWAyTHY9cqN7Q==

"@firebase/installations@0.4.20":
  version "0.4.20"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/installations/-/installations-0.4.20.tgz#e52a5904c41ac0be0bb2ab1e320b8e1018ed2630"
  integrity sha512-ddUPZQKHWJzqg3g11hxHIPhp3oMEmsPo0GSxtp9Xd2VLRU64MFNAAt5PiBbq1K92ukZVoNh6Ki6J6+hJEQcGQw==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/installations-types" "0.3.4"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    idb "3.0.2"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/installations@0.4.21":
  version "0.4.21"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/installations/-/installations-0.4.21.tgz#152fae36647eb08c1e94f94ca160d3273a401117"
  integrity sha512-tMoAb1lHAQefdknWbKxSp2CEWWV/f4aeq4PjhzWurJEJN4RQ620ITbtuKregnGnYHu9lDzhyZ51H4s6+BhjCxA==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/installations-types" "0.3.4"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    idb "3.0.2"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/logger@0.2.6":
  version "0.2.6"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/logger/-/logger-0.2.6.tgz#3aa2ca4fe10327cabf7808bd3994e88db26d7989"
  integrity sha512-KIxcUvW/cRGWlzK9Vd2KB864HlUnCfdTH0taHE0sXW5Xl7+W68suaeau1oKNEqmc3l45azkd4NzXTCWZRZdXrw==

"@firebase/logger@0.3.0":
  version "0.3.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/logger/-/logger-0.3.0.tgz#a3992e40f62c10276dbfcb8b4ab376b7e25d7fd9"
  integrity sha512-7oQ+TctqekfgZImWkKuda50JZfkmAKMgh5qY4aR4pwRyqZXuJXN1H/BKkHvN1y0S4XWtF0f/wiCLKHhyi1ppPA==
  dependencies:
    tslib "^2.1.0"

"@firebase/messaging-types@0.5.0":
  version "0.5.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/messaging-types/-/messaging-types-0.5.0.tgz#c5d0ef309ced1758fda93ef3ac70a786de2e73c4"
  integrity sha512-QaaBswrU6umJYb/ZYvjR5JDSslCGOH6D9P136PhabFAHLTR4TWjsaACvbBXuvwrfCXu10DtcjMxqfhdNIB1Xfg==

"@firebase/messaging@0.7.4":
  version "0.7.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/messaging/-/messaging-0.7.4.tgz#d527506de7690731f0a83e6a82a6aa590b14523a"
  integrity sha512-xIZ1vHnOcHAaj+H/gS8tu3QolR9up+fyTfgVLEFbZRsbAiLuIvuaoJwTHLAUTs/nJF6GtEGscRD4Jx/aFmEJRw==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.20"
    "@firebase/messaging-types" "0.5.0"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    idb "3.0.2"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/messaging@0.7.5":
  version "0.7.5"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/messaging/-/messaging-0.7.5.tgz#1efe40b1785535ee13af323b7f2deb7cceb2a94a"
  integrity sha512-jA1pdV/DrfvzSVKLuff2hYo2AvU0CdZ901TngxscJqKYViZEoqAGw2v/kC70uRwEG0Tc2M/SRHstHpeFADlP0Q==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.21"
    "@firebase/messaging-types" "0.5.0"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    idb "3.0.2"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/performance-types@0.0.13":
  version "0.0.13"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/performance-types/-/performance-types-0.0.13.tgz#58ce5453f57e34b18186f74ef11550dfc558ede6"
  integrity sha512-6fZfIGjQpwo9S5OzMpPyqgYAUZcFzZxHFqOyNtorDIgNXq33nlldTL/vtaUZA8iT9TT5cJlCrF/jthKU7X21EA==

"@firebase/performance@0.4.6":
  version "0.4.6"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/performance/-/performance-0.4.6.tgz#e6b8b4c7c21e657af3a8e87c422cd4d199b57fa1"
  integrity sha512-fy9YPYnvePFxme7euyi8B658gF8JUQhAB1qv6hVw+HqjVZQIANhwM9AUBi9+5jikD7gD1CnU7EjREvoy8MJiAw==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.20"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/performance-types" "0.0.13"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/performance@0.4.7":
  version "0.4.7"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/performance/-/performance-0.4.7.tgz#be201b76667f59aabd31e7fb73977ed5b172d0c3"
  integrity sha512-wxau4qrAy5W+kIoXPUm5hJVX4+vY3wVC9QqWNzoqb+L5tMHxIoeEqxvJo8abjv4pa0/YaVl1XKAZdvvoe7c/dA==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.21"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/performance-types" "0.0.13"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/polyfill@0.3.36":
  version "0.3.36"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/polyfill/-/polyfill-0.3.36.tgz#c057cce6748170f36966b555749472b25efdb145"
  integrity sha512-zMM9oSJgY6cT2jx3Ce9LYqb0eIpDE52meIzd/oe/y70F+v9u1LDqk5kUF5mf16zovGBWMNFmgzlsh6Wj0OsFtg==
  dependencies:
    core-js "3.6.5"
    promise-polyfill "8.1.3"
    whatwg-fetch "2.0.4"

"@firebase/remote-config-types@0.1.9":
  version "0.1.9"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/remote-config-types/-/remote-config-types-0.1.9.tgz#fe6bbe4d08f3b6e92fce30e4b7a9f4d6a96d6965"
  integrity sha512-G96qnF3RYGbZsTRut7NBX0sxyczxt1uyCgXQuH/eAfUCngxjEGcZQnBdy6mvSdqdJh5mC31rWPO4v9/s7HwtzA==

"@firebase/remote-config@0.1.31":
  version "0.1.31"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/remote-config/-/remote-config-0.1.31.tgz#092cefc946558a1924d34960163f19b1adf8253d"
  integrity sha512-QWjDsrLSqQnq/YTb3TSOJtIv7z2GXB7mTiwXE43NxYmsOX2z8KBlBBEHf9TcWk+90MKUTFfurDgYJN4rlIOxPg==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.20"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/remote-config-types" "0.1.9"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/remote-config@0.1.32":
  version "0.1.32"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/remote-config/-/remote-config-0.1.32.tgz#a3ffac5039b6a785d83bf5864b58b06fe0b8cfea"
  integrity sha512-nPPhKSUHgwlv2hazke6keBkkadW+/VCpNbq3P9L8oWxq7hKQz7MYAC5LU6PqexNmWQqGFiYyX5J8XDUU3gH/NQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/installations" "0.4.21"
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/remote-config-types" "0.1.9"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/rules-unit-testing@1.2.4":
  version "1.2.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/-/rules-unit-testing-1.2.4.tgz#7c378f7f0e277cf84016946b6d6af269a439e25a"
  integrity sha512-suYV3B3UaZS/+4x+94gAaAZTaYn7r3du5h4lYunvY4LAzimtv8sVFhxNvlfV3awDCJUoAMlh6MFAm7wg2rXJ4g==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/logger" "0.2.6"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    firebase "8.3.0"
    request "2.88.2"

"@firebase/storage-types@0.3.13":
  version "0.3.13"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/storage-types/-/storage-types-0.3.13.tgz#cd43e939a2ab5742e109eb639a313673a48b5458"
  integrity sha512-pL7b8d5kMNCCL0w9hF7pr16POyKkb3imOW7w0qYrhBnbyJTdVxMWZhb0HxCFyQWC0w3EiIFFmxoz8NTFZDEFog==

"@firebase/storage@0.4.3":
  version "0.4.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/storage/-/storage-0.4.3.tgz#8800fa61131890f64448b4ab536c8ee1ba9bdcdf"
  integrity sha512-53IIt6Z3BltPBPmvxF/RGlvW8nBl4wI9GMR52CjRAIj438tPNxbpIvkLB956VVB9gfZhDcPIKxg7hNtC7hXrkA==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.0"
    "@firebase/storage-types" "0.3.13"
    "@firebase/util" "0.3.4"
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/storage@0.4.4":
  version "0.4.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/storage/-/storage-0.4.4.tgz#e1cca95706a1a25c551134b687be975fa4853a49"
  integrity sha512-3mH6IR04Lvk16kQQ7CMumpppNcqN6RVcqSD3jzaB8P6vbzDVRyk7Dnhd00Eigd++q5FdNRpW3h8xGvHPWDYfKQ==
  dependencies:
    "@firebase/component" "0.2.1"
    "@firebase/storage-types" "0.3.13"
    "@firebase/util" "0.4.0"
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/util@0.3.4":
  version "0.3.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/util/-/util-0.3.4.tgz#e389d0e0e2aac88a5235b06ba9431db999d4892b"
  integrity sha512-VwjJUE2Vgr2UMfH63ZtIX9Hd7x+6gayi6RUXaTqEYxSbf/JmehLmAEYSuxS/NckfzAXWeGnKclvnXVibDgpjQQ==
  dependencies:
    tslib "^1.11.1"

"@firebase/util@0.4.0":
  version "0.4.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/util/-/util-0.4.0.tgz#8db3d39e0ed7b991b4da2435d7e6556cb1bd6672"
  integrity sha512-z8A+9YGM61ZXQ2KBSVwxXaELOJjG+EQ374YolqNVMvWBJzTNGZGaVP81Ggl8XD10Xinyt1Dgdo86JDV0OAnvqA==
  dependencies:
    tslib "^2.0.0"

"@firebase/util@1.4.0":
  version "1.4.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/util/-/util-1.4.0.tgz#81e985adba44b4d1f21ec9f5af9628d505891de8"
  integrity sha512-Qn58d+DVi1nGn0bA9RV89zkz0zcbt6aUcRdyiuub/SuEvjKYstWmHcHwh1C0qmE1wPf9a3a+AuaRtduaGaRT7A==
  dependencies:
    tslib "^2.1.0"

"@firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.4.1":
  version "0.4.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/-/webchannel-wrapper-0.4.1.tgz#600f2275ff54739ad5ac0102f1467b8963cd5f71"
  integrity sha512-0yPjzuzGMkW1GkrC8yWsiN7vt1OzkMIi9HgxRmKREZl2wnNPOKo/yScTjXf/O57HM8dltqxPF6jlNLFVtc2qdw==
```

Comment: i am using npm so there is no yarn.lock ,but i tried using a old version but getting the same error again